# Speeding up the classification process - PCA combined with SVM?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm, pca

I have a cyclic method running which collects a data set of 15.000 feature vectors with 30 dimensions (every 200ms). My current setup simply feeds all raw feature vectors to a SVM with RBF (Radial basis function). The classification result is rather unconvincing as being costly in terms of time. I know that the dataset isn't that big, so classification in real-time could be possible with the right subsampling feature vector or so. The goal is to speed up the entire classification process (training/prediction) to reach a few milliseconds. To obtain an unsupervised classification approach, I currently run k-means to label the feature vectors. I pick a few cluster results and assign them class 1 and all others class 0.

The idea now the following:

- collect all 15.000 (N) feature vectors with 30 (D) dimensions
- PCA on all N feature vectors
- use the eigenvalues to determine a feature vector with (d) dimensions (d < D)
- Fed the new set of (n < N)

  - feature vectors
  - or: the eigenvectors ?
    to train the svm

Maybe instead of SVM a KNN approach would result in similar result?
Does this approach makes sense? 
Any ideas to improve the process or change it in order to speed it up? 
How do I determine the best number of d?

The classification accuracy shouldn't suffer too much from the time reduction.

**EDIT: Data stream mining**
I was just reading about Data Stream Mining. I think this topic fits my setup quite well since I have to extract knowledge structures from continuous, rapid data records. Maybe I should replace the SVM with a Gradient Boosted Tree?

Thanks!

Comment: There are some things missing: is your data labeled? Each "pack"? How many datapoints you classify later? In other words - what is the most important part - speed of training or speed of classification (or both?)?

Comment: My data is labelled by picking with apriori knowledge a subset of feature vectors clustered by k-means. So my data has a label of either 0 or 1. Right now in every cycle I classify the 15.000 feature vectors based on the trained SVM from the last cycle. In terms of speed, preferably both.

Comment: Why just last cycle? Why you do not use the model from **all previous cycles** (it changes types of models we can work with)?

Comment: Oh yes, sure, inartfully expressed myself here. I only train one SVM and every cycle train it with the new 15k feature vectors. So all previous features contribute to the model.